# yum info vim does not have any matching packages to list

Tags: package-management, yum

Why doesn't `yum info vim` return information about vim, which is installed on my Fedora 34 machine?

```
[root@oatmeal ~]# yum info vim
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:02 ago on Wed 08 Sep 2021 08:01:25 EDT.
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

`vim` is installed and configured on my host:

```
[root@oatmeal ~]# which vim
/usr/bin/vim
[root@oatmeal ~]# vim --version | head -n 4                                                                                                                                                                                                   
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Sep 06 2021 00:00:00)
Included patches: 1-3404
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
```

There is information available about other installed packages:

```
[root@oatmeal ~]# yum info openssl                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:49 ago on Wed 08 Sep 2021 08:01:25 EDT.
Installed Packages
Name         : openssl
Epoch        : 1
Version      : 1.1.1l
Release      : 1.fc34
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 1.1 M
Source       : openssl-1.1.1l-1.fc34.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : Utilities from the general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
URL          : http://www.openssl.org/
License      : OpenSSL and ASL 2.0
Description  : The OpenSSL toolkit provides support for secure communications between
             : machines. OpenSSL includes a certificate management tool and shared
             : libraries which provide various cryptographic algorithms and
             : protocols.

[root@oatmeal ~]# yum info firefox 
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:56 ago on Wed 08 Sep 2021 08:01:25 EDT.
Installed Packages
Name         : firefox
Version      : 91.0.2
Release      : 1.fc34
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 253 M
Source       : firefox-91.0.2-1.fc34.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : Mozilla Firefox Web browser
URL          : https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/
License      : MPLv1.1 or GPLv2+ or LGPLv2+
Description  : Mozilla Firefox is an open-source web browser, designed for standards
             : compliance, performance and portability.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `yum info vim` doesn’t show anything is that the package providing `vim` (the binary) isn’t `vim`, it’s `vim-enhanced`.

`rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/vim` will tell you what package provides the binary in question, and `yum info vim-enhanced` (or `dnf info vim-enhanced`) will show you the information about the package.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I can confirm that was the issue via `yum info $(rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/vim) | wc -l \ 26`

Answer (score 0):

If it is on later version of rpm-based distro, then they moved on to dnf. If you think the package is already installed, you can try `dnf list --installed vim*`. Otherwise, if you think the package is not installed, you can substitute installed with 'available'```

Comment: `yum` is a symlink to `dnf-3` in F34. Using `yum info` or `dnf info` doesn’t make any difference.